# Converting HTML TAG Object to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to convert the html tag objects to json object in the javascript in order to send them to the server from the javascript. As i have to save these objects at the Ruby on Rails server.  These HTML objects is the canvas tag object and the graphics objects created using CAKE API. I have used the stringify function but it is not working.
Here is my code:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var CAKECanvas = new Canvas(document.body, 1000,1000);
    var canvas=CAKECanvas.canvas;
    var text=document.createElement('textarea');
    text.id="text";
    text.rows="100";
    text.cols="200";
    document.body.appendChild(text);
    canvas.style.borderStyle="solid";
    canvas.style.borderColor="black";
var rect= new Circle();
    rect.radius=100;
    rect.centered=true;
    rect.cx=Math.random() * 500;
    rect.cy= Math.random() * 300;
    rect.stroke= false;
    rect.fill= "red";
    rect.xDir = Math.random() > 0.5?1:-1;
rect.yDir = Math.random() > 0.5?1:-1;
    var obj=new Object;
    var count = 0,k;
    for (k in rect)
        {
            if (rect.hasOwnProperty(k))
                {
                    count++;
                    obj[k]=rect[k];
                }
        }
    alert(count);
rect.addFrameListener(function(t, dt)
    {
                this.cx += this.xDir * 50 * dt/1000;
        this.cy += this.yDir * 50 * dt/1000;
        if (this.cx > 550)
        {
            this.xDir = -1;
        }
        if (this.cx < 50)
        {
            this.xDir = 1;
        }
        if (this.cy > 350)
        {
            this.yDir = -1;
        }
        if (this.cy < 50)
        {
            this.yDir = 1;
        }
    }
);

CAKECanvas.append(rect);
    var carAsJSON = JSON.stringify(obj); /////////////////NOT CONVERTING THE OBJECT OBJ     INTO JSON OBJECT
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example page? Did you include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) in your HTML? What's the error?

Comment: @Marcel: there is no example page. stringify function is not working. It is converting it to json object. No I have not include json2,js

Comment: But what's the error? If `JSON.stringify` is not defined somewhere (e.g., in json2.js or a native browser's implementation), it won't work.

Comment: @Marcel: I have included the json2.js but is not converting the object obj into json object.

Comment: When I try to run your code from within an empty HTML page, I already get an error on line 3 (`new Canvas`): “Canvas is not defined”.

Comment: You have to include Google CAKE api cake.js. You can tell me your email, I can send you all the file.
Link of cake api:
http://cakejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/cake.js

Comment: @Marcel: I want to send these objects to rails server. How can i do this as JSON.stringify does not work on objects. I have tried converting them into array but it still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only primitive values (strings, dates, booleans, numbers) and objects and array structures are possible to serialize into JSON. This mean that other host-objects like RegExp or Canvas cannot be serialized.

In short, JSON is limited to **data** ('information').

So, you will either have to save the created markup using .innerHTML, or save the data so that it can be recreated.

Comment: @Sean: Can I directly send javascript objects to server. if it is then how.

Comment: No, you have to pass it using a format that is common to both the client- and the server-side programming environments. As of now, that is JSON.
See json.org for _the_ description of what JSON is.

Comment: @cooldude: But, as Sean already said, you can't `stringify` anything else than data (so, not functions or HTML elements).

Comment: @Sean,@Marcel: ok fine. Then I will try other options. Thanks for giving time into my problem and providing suggestions

Comment: @Sean,@Marcel: One last thing . Can i directly send the javascript objects to server without stringifying them. As i m handling the server. So, i will take care of it.

Comment: No, javascript objects are just that, objects. They live in the memory of the client just as serverside objects live in the memory of the server. These objects has nothing in common except for the notion of what an 'object' is and so to 'pass' an object from one to the other, these have to agree on some sort of common language. this language is JSON. The sender has to serialize (stringify) the object, and the recipient has to deserialize (parse) it.

Comment: Think of it as moving a chair over the internet. You cannot transfer the real chair, but you can transfer the characteristics (type of material, height, width, length etc...) of the chair so that it can be rebuilt on the other end. That is what serializing/deserializing is about.