# Complex Javascript objects to JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, html, json

> Duplicate: [Converting HTML TAG Object to JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891476/converting-html-tag-object-to-json-object)

Hi,
   Is there is any Javascript API that converts complex Javascript Objects To JSON String???

Comment: What do you mean by "complex" ?

Comment: How complex are you referring too?

Comment: @cooldude give a sample of it?

Comment: JSON.stringify (from `http://www.json.org/json2.js`) serializes nested objects, arrays, numbers, strings, bools, and null.  Do you need more?

Comment: @CMS,@gurun8,@Pandiya,@Joey: By complex objects I mean Html Tag object like Canvas object, graphics objects created by Cake Api. Example I Have provided in previous post:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891476/converting-html-tag-object-to-json-object.

Comment: Your previous question asks the same thing in more detail, this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Why are you asking duplicate questions? We already gave you the correct answer in the other thread.

Comment: @Sean: I was asking further to know that any existing api developed by someone to convert complex objects as it supports primitive types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you're looking for a an `API` per se. That would be a something like a service where you send data and receive back something else.

What you want is called a **serializer**. It turns a javascript object into a string of text representing the object-literal. For example:

```
var foo = {};
foo[bar] = "baz";

//do serializing to get a -string- that looks like this:

{bar: "baz"}
```

That way when a service receives this JSON information, if it uses javascript, it's already in a format where it can be read directly into memory without conversion. Here is an example javascript serializer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: I have an example which it was not converting which i have sent in my previous post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891476/converting-html-tag-object-to-json-object